# Vb.net Login Session and Mysql Query

Tags: mysql, vb.net, session

I have a login page that i want to collect a users id and use a session to store it so i can use it on the redirect page.

Login Page :

```
Dim Query As String
            Query = "select * from mdxmain.taffiliate where affID = '" & username.Text & "' and affPassword = '" & password.Text & "'"
            COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
            Session("affID") = username.Text
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("affID", userid)

            READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader

            Dim count As Integer
            count = 0

            While READER.Read
                count = count + 1
            End While

            If count = 1 Then


                Response.Redirect("dashboard.aspx")

            Else
                Literal1.Text = "Invalid credentials"
            End If

            MysqlConn.Close()

        Finally

        End Try
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
```

and the dashboard.aspx page that has a query in it :

```
Dim c As New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=test;UID=test;PWD=test;")
        c.Open()
        Dim com As New MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM toutcome WHERE AffID = 'MW0011' AND CompletedDate >= CURDATE();", c)
        Dim myReader As MySqlDataReader = com.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        myReader.Read()
        Label1.Text = myReader.Item(0).ToString()
```

Now what i want to do is the customer logs in using his ID and i want to copy that ID into a session and then use it in the above query (replace MW0011 with the session id) , please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace the query `WHERE AffID = 'MW0011'` with `WHERE AffID = '" & CType(Session.Item("affID"), String) & "'`

Comment: Do i need to first load the session in the new page before i can use it ?